# InfoWindows only some markers

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I use a lot of markers en mi google maps, in a markers I show a infowindows with a picture and a long text, but I want the others markers shows the default title form with a simple text.

Any idea??

Thanks!!

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

In your `InfoWindowAdapter`, return `null` from `getInfoContents()` for those info windows for which you want the default info window to appear.